# How to join these two tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Here are my tables:

### employees

- id
- name
- salary
- dept_id

### departments

- id
- name

---

```
SELECT  employees.id, employees.name, empolyees.dept_id, departments.id, 
     departments.name
FROM employees, departments
WHERE employees.dept_id = departments.dept_id
ORDER BY employees.name;
```

Am I joining these two tables right?

Comment: What do German zip codes (`PLZ`)  have to do with this?

Comment: Follow the advice of the other answers: use explicit INNER JOIN syntax.  In addition, the query you have provided won't work because you have not spelled `employees` consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use the explicit join syntax

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, e.dept_id, d.id, d.name
FROM empolyees e
INNER JOIN departments d ON e.dept_id = d.id
ORDER BY e.name
```

And you used `departments.dept_id` which does not exist. It is `departments.id`

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. You used the wrong `deparment.dept_id` column. The syntax you used generally works but is very old style and should be used any more.

Answer (score 0):

could say:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, empolyees.dept_id, d.id, d.name 
FROM employees e
inner join departments d on e.dept_id = d.dept_id 
ORDER BY e.name;
```